A tool to split a PDF based on chapter or section
I'm working with some rather large PDFs, some in the neighborhood of 1700-2000 pages.  Those become rather unwieldy to work with, but they're formatted nicely into different chapters or sections.  It can still be cumbersome to jump back and forth between different sections if I'm trying to compare them though, or if I'm trying to use a section as input to, say, an LLM but don't want it to try to deal with the entire document.
What I think would be useful to me is a (preferably command line so I can incorporate it easily into a scripted workflow) tool that would be able to recognize the different sections and create a new file that contains only those sections.  I'd be willing to accept it if it split it so all the pages that contain parts of the section were in the different files, even if that means that the page that has the end of one section and the start of another appears in both chapter files.
Much of the work that would use this is being done on an Ubuntu system, though RHEL flavor systems are available as well.  I could even use a Windows solution, though the Linux-based solutions are preferred.
It seems many of the solutions I see are able to either split each page into a file or a specified range of pages.  I don't know of a tool that is able to automatically detect, say, the sections that are used to build a table of contents (or even just using the TOC).  I suppose I could manually grab the pages referenced in the TOC and use those as the bounds for a range of pages to include to a tool like pdftk, but I'm hoping there's a more automated and less error prone solution (as anything that requires me to enter the data correct must be).
A tool would be ideal, but if there is a library (ideally in Python, but C, Java and likely others may work) I could attempt to write this functionality myself with it.

To be clear, these PDFs don't have a table of contents (i.e the kind which shows alongside the document in a PDF reader, not the kind which is on the page)?

@johnwhitington Ideally that would not be required, but I do have some that have that sidebar navigation so a tool that made use of that would still be of some benefit

Where the file already has a document outline, you can run
cpdf -split-bookmarks <level> in.pdf -o out%%%.pdf
which will split on bookmarks of the given level and below (where 0 is top-level, 1 the next level and so on) to out001.pdf, out002.pdf and so on.
See sections 2.2 and 2.3 of the manual for details, and more options.

Thanks for the tip.  Look at the project at https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries does look like it has some promise for my needs

Depending on the visual appearance of the text, the ABBYY OCR engine semi-accurately tries to identify relative text stylings i.e. chapter headings, topical subheadings, body text, etc. It then, as part of the final save step following OCR, attempts to use these to build a bookmarks tree. Sometimes this works extremely well; just as often, it doesn't work.
No perfect automated solution to build such a bookmarks tree exists, unfortunately. (I doubt any machine will ever be able to do that perfectly.) I use a combination of this automation, manual build from text TOC as you mention, and finally (most useful once you understand how to do this) regex arguments that seek particular text strings, generated for the autobookmark functions in Pdf-X-Change editor and/or Adobe Acrobat (with the Evermap autobookmark plugin).
But: once you have a TOC, splitting by section is easy as pie. I use PDF-X-Change Editor to do this. See images. Acrobat also has a function to do it, and probably other editors do too.

Hope this eases your trouble somewhat.

This looks like an interesting thing I'll have to explore.  I had not thought of using OCR at try to do it, so you've definitely opened a door I need to go through.
